# Can I check what my reputation was on a particular date?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph, dates

After looking through the sites and stack apps, I have not found a way to check my reputation at a particular date.

Is this at all possible through the User pages or API?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Other than the [recalc page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133159/162704), you can also check your [network reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/40556/stuperuser?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 9):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

After each day when you earn (or lose) reputation you'll see a line like:

> -- 2010-10-08 rep +50   = 28917

So look for the date you're interested in in this output and you'll see what reputation you had on that day.

Comment: Which would be accurate barring all posts that contributed to the reputation score that were deleted after that date.

Comment: Nice link, it also displays this information `earned at least 200 reputation on X days` , I was looking for it.